Character creation focused TTRPG
Are there TTRPGs such as "The quiet year", "The ground itself" and "Microscope" but with a focus on giving a history and depth to a character instead of a place? I specifically like that the world-building games (like "The quiet year" and "The ground itself") make you think about questions you normally wouldn't, resulting in a less shallow world and would love to find something similar for characters (ideally characters are developed as a group).

Welcome to the stack Emiel, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Game recommendation questions are off topic here, though your question may be on topic at a traditional discussion forum.

This feels crucially different from game-rec to me: it’s not “recommend the best game for doing this?” it’s “are any games specifically designed for doing this?” It might still devolve into the same kind of popularity contest mess we had with game-rec, and there’s certainly room within the preposterously over-broad non-consensus policy to say it’s off-topic even if it doesn't do that, but I, for one, think it’s best to wait and see on this question.

Can't you just use one of the listed systems, but elaborate on a character instead of a world?

Microscope could be repurposed easily but seems to me like the worst of the three systems for something like this. The other two ask specific questions about the world which would take some effort to find a character based equivalent for each. All seem imperfect solutions, hence my question.

@KRyan I feel like both those ways of framing the question fall in the same category of "Shopping" question. At the end of the day, the question is always about recommendations for a game system, which are most definitely off-topic. Which is why I'm voting to keep closed.

@Matthieu I acknowledged that, but as I alluded to, consensus for that policy—at that breadth—was never demonstrated, that was a policy inappropriately forced on the community by the diamond moderators at the time.

@KRyan that's a fair point. Maybe this could be worth discussing once more in meta. At the very least it'd probably be more worthwhile to do so than acting directly on this specific Q&A, I believe.

@Matthieu In terms of the entire policy, sure, but that’s too much work and there’s too much bad blood. (The arguments about it when it first happened were intense.) All I’m saying is that here, for this question, there’s reason to have some hope and reason to not bow to the policy, so letting this one go is valid. And it might still turn out terribly! I just think it’s worth finding out if it actually does.

@KRyan not having taken part in that original situation, I don't have any strong feeling about one way or the other, and I'm still unsure whether this policy is worth keeping or not. However, it is true that if there is room for reworking the policy, this question, which is somewhat on the edge of game-rec, could be a good candidate to try and find out. You've convinced me, I'm voting to reopen.

@KRyan The don’t guess the system policy discussions and ultimate dismantling went down without any issues. Perhaps it’s been long enough now for this broader policy discussion to occur again without problems?

@ThomasMarkov I think a policy discussion in meta would be worthwhile.  I've thought that way for a long time, just never had the personal time to invest in getting it started.

@Novak Then what do you think about us having a chat discussion with our moderators about getting that started? My understanding is that they had a bit of internal discussion around framing the DGtS policy meta, and I think having them guide things on meta was part of the success of that policy decision.

@ThomasMarkov if memory serves, the policy predates both of us, so it is probably wise to have that chat in some venue.  It is business hours in my time zone, so I'm not sure I could join at this moment.
